# In Kotlin native, how to free resources wrapped inside an object, when the wrapping object is freed

Tags: kotlin-native

In Kotlin/JVM and Java this is a fairly easy answer: either use the `finalize` method or a `ReferenceQueue` (the first is deprecated, the second is the preferred mechanism since Java 9).

In Kotlin/Native none of them is present and the documentation doesn't mention anything about freeing resources, only about using GC to handle Kotlin-based resources.

The scenario is like this:

I want to create a wrapper object for some C-allocated data, that have been passed around, given to other classes, or being returned and stored in collections passed around etc etc. Thus solutions like `memscope` etc are not valid. I need something that gets notified when the wrapped object goes out of scope, to free its resources.

Is there something like this in Kotlin/Native, and if not, what can I do instead?